# HTML5 rendering with old css

Tags: html, css

I'm using a menu component which uses HTML5 and CSS3.

The component only works if I set the tag  in the start of page. OK!

However, when I set this tag, the old CSS style stops working. The color and the font isn't changed

The CSS is declared as follow:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cbpp.css" />
```

The CSS is:

```
textoouro_pequeno {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: italic;
color: DED7A8;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

The link which uses the css is the follow:

```
<a href="http://www.cartedaparati.com.br" class='textoouro_pequeno'>Página Principal</a>
```

Is there changes what should I do in the css?

Thanks a lot

André

Comment: Hex colour codes need a "#" prefix."color: #DED7A8;"

Comment: The value of the `color` property needs a `#` in front of it.  As in: `color: #DED7A8;`

Comment: Strange tags you have in your document `textoouro_pequeno `.

Answer (score 4):

Your css declaration doesn't refer to a class at the moment -- you need to update it to be

```
.textoouro_pequeno {
```

or

```
a.textoouro_pequeno {
```

Otherwise it tries to point towards a tag called textoouro_pequeno, but there is no HTML tag by that name.

Also, the comments above are correct: color needs "#" in front of it.

Comment: For more information on how to declare classes and id's in your css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp